# Virtual Environment for Erlang

Tags: erlang, virtualenv

I want to learn Erlang and maybe Elixir. I have used virtualenvwrapper for my Django projects, and also for NodeJS and find it very useful.

I would like to use it my Erlang test if possible. I have searched PyPI and google it for a solution and not found much info... I have found a elixir version manager, exenv. And envirius and kerl for erlang.

Would like to know your opinion on these managers? Or if I missed a better one...

EDIT

What options we have for a virtual environment in Erlang?

Comment: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang

Comment: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-elixir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need virtual environment for Erlang/Elixir, what you try to solve with it?
In my mind virtualenv in Python is used for separating system-level python libs from project-level.
This is not a problem in Erlang/Elixir because of project is acts like "virtualenv" and rebar or mix installs dependencies in it.

Comment: no trying to solve anything, only avoid conflicts between erlang versions.

Comment: then kerl looks good for this

Comment: I will accept your answer. Although I think will go with envirius because it looks more like virtualenv.